# How to show that X is complete, when f is an homeomorphism and lipschitz continuous and Y is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a Lipschitz continuous function, and $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ are metric spaces. I need to show, that if $f$ is an homeomorphism and $Y$ is complete, then $X$ is complete.

I dont understand this, because I saw an example of an homeomorphism $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Which would mean that $X$ is not complete? Or has it something to do with the fact its Lipschitz?

Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: What have you tried? Btw: the homeomorphism between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$ is usually some scaled version of $\tan$, which is not Lipschitz. In fact, if $X$ is bounded, then $Y$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, the Lipschitz condition guarantees that $(f(x_n))$ is also Cauchy, hence has a limit $y$. By continuity of $f^{-1}$, $(x_n)$ converges to $f^{-1}(y)$.